# Next.js unable to get image from external localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm encountering an error in my Next.js 14 project when trying to display an image from localhost:8081 using the Image component from 'next/image'. The backend is in Java, which sends the image.

[next image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIZg.png)

Here is the code snippet where I'm using the Image component:

```
'use client'

import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen'>
            <Image
                src={'http://localhost:8081/api/image/get/1'}
                alt='image'
                width={200}
                height={200}
            />
            Hello world!!!
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I use a regular  tag, there is no error.

I've tried configuring my next.config.mjs as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    image: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: '8081',
                pathname: '/api/image/get/**',
            },
        ],
    },
}

export default nextConfig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is using an incorrect key (`image` instead of `images`). It should be like this:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'http',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port: '8081',
                pathname: '/api/image/get/**',
            },
        ],
    },
}

export default nextConfig
```

[You can find the documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/images).